# Getting 'Specified cast is not valid.' Error on MVC SqlDataReader

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, sqldatareader

Please don't mark this as **DUPLICATE QUESTION.**
I've been trying to do follow all the answers I have found but I still get this error. Can anyone give me idea where this error came from ??

Here's the error

```
 Server Error in '/NomsPR' Application.

Specified cast is not valid.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Source Error: 


Line 36:                     while (reader.Read())
Line 37:                     {
Line 38:                              results.Add( new NomsPRItem()
Line 39:                             {
Line 40:                                 RequestID = reader.GetInt32(0)

Source File: c:\SVN\branches\NomsPRMonitoring\NomsPRMonitoring\Models\CheckerConnection.cs    Line: 38 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32() +6639748
   Lear.NomsPRMonitoring.Models.CheckerConnection.LoadPRItems(DateTime from, DateTime to) in c:\SVN\branches\NomsPRMonitoring\NomsPRMonitoring\Models\CheckerConnection.cs:38
   Lear.NomsPRMonitoring.Controllers.CheckerController.GetList() in c:\SVN\branches\NomsPRMonitoring\NomsPRMonitoring\Controllers\CheckerController.cs:33
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +261
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +124
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +838499
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +839052
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Here is my model :

```
public class NomsPRItem 
    {
        public long RequestID { get; set; }
        public long PartID { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartDesc { get; set; }
        public string UnitName { get; set; }
        public double PartQuantity { get; set; }
        public string CurrName { get; set; }
        public double PiecePrice { get; set; }
        public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
        public string ProposeSuppliers { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public long AccountTypeID { get; set; }
        public string AccountType { get; set; }
        public string InboxLearUID { get; set; }
        public bool ReviewFlag { get; set; }
        public long SubCatID { get; set; }
        public string SubCatName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string CreateBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastDate { get; set; }
        public string LastBy { get; set; }
        public string SupplierID { get; set; }
        public string CostCenter { get; set; }
        public long SubAccountTypeID { get; set; }
        public string SubAccountType { get; set; }

        public double TotalAmount { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my connection

```
 public static List<NomsPRItem> LoadPRItems(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        string sSrcipt = m_sReport + "and p.[RequestDate] between '" + from.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' and '" + to.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'";
        List<NomsPRItem> results = new List<NomsPRItem>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(m_sConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sSrcipt, con))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                         results.Add( new NomsPRItem()
                        {
                            RequestID = reader.GetInt32(0)
                            ,PartID = reader.GetInt32(15)
                            ,PartDesc = reader.GetString(1)
                            ,PartNumber = reader.GetString(7)
                            ,SupplierID = reader.GetString(16)
                            ,AccountType = reader.GetString(3)
                            ,CurrName = reader.GetString(4)
                            ,PartQuantity = (double)reader.GetDecimal(5)
                            ,PiecePrice = (double)reader.GetDecimal(6)
                            ,Amount = (double)reader.GetDecimal(5) * (double)reader.GetDecimal(6)
                        });
                }
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

I am using angularjs in this, so I am converting this data to JSON ..

Here is my controller :

```
 public JsonResult GetList()
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        List<NomsPRItem> model = CheckerConnection.LoadPRItems(new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0), today);
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetReportList(string from, string to)
    {
        DateTime fromd = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime tod = DateTime.Now;
        if (from != "undefined")
            fromd = Convert.ToDateTime(from);
        if (to != "undefined")
            tod = Convert.ToDateTime(to);
        fromd = new DateTime(fromd.Year, fromd.Month, fromd.Day, 0, 0, 0);
        tod = new DateTime(tod.Year, tod.Month, tod.Day, 23, 59, 59);
        return Json(CheckerConnection.LoadPRItems(fromd, tod), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I hope someone can help me on this mistake !

Comment: It looks like the error occurs when calling reader.GetInt32(0).

This is simply a matter of debugging: the SqlDataReader expects to find an int in your DB but there's something on that position that can't be cast to integer.

Try setting breakpoints so you can investigate if this happens at every record or just (a) certain record(s). You might have some faulty data somewhere.

Comment: Your requestid is long and you are assigning it a Int32 value.

Comment: What will assign on it ??  @MairajAhmad ..

Comment: Debug and check on which line do you get this exception.

Comment: @MairajAhmad i got this error on line 38  `results.Add( new NomsPRItem()`

Comment: Change RequestID = reader.GetInt32(0) to RequestID = reader.GetInt64(0) do same for PartID. Just converting values to long.

Comment: Surpised to see commas at the begining of the row, not very readable, but it's just a detail !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requestID is `long` and you are converting it to `Int32`.Change it to `Int64` like this.

```
RequestID = reader.GetInt64(0)
,PartID = reader.GetInt64(15)
```

Comment: Nice answer. Did answer my problem